# The area of the triangle enclosed by the axes and the tangent to the curve y = 1/ x , at any point on the parabola is

Tags: calculus

Consider the following diagram:
[image]
A point on the curve is chosen, and the tangent line is drawn until it intersects the axes, delimiting a triangle (in grey). How can we find the area of the triangle, for an arbitrary chosen point on the curve?

I can't figure out what to do after finding the slope of tangent

Comment: Come up with an equation of the line. You know the point of tangency and the slope of the tangent line at that point.

Comment: the point of tangency is not given

Comment: y = 1/x is the equation of a *hyperbola*

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of the second part of [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656053/show-that-the-area-of-the-triangle-does-not-depend-on-the-location-of-the-point?rq=1).

Comment: You don't need the point of tangencey given. Take an arbitrary $(a,1/a)$ on the graph and work with it.

Comment: @zhw. Thank you for the clarification. This is what I meant when I said “you have the point of tangency.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Now use the formula $$y-y_o=m(x-x_o)$$
$$y-y_o=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(x-x_o)$$
$$y-\frac{1}{x_o}=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(x-x_o)$$
$$0-\frac{1}{x_o}=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(x-x_o)$$
Now multiply both sides of the equation with $x_o^2$
$$x_o^2\left(-\frac{1}{x_o}\right)=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(x-x_o)\cdot x_o^2$$
$$-x_o=-1(x-x_o)$$
$$2x_o=x$$
This is value of $x$ intercept and in the similar way find the value of $y$ intercept.
$$y-y_o=m(x-x_o)$$
$$y-y_o=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(x-x_o)$$
$$y-\frac{1}{x_o}=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(x-x_o)$$
$$y-\frac{1}{x_o}=\frac{-1}{x_o^2}(0-x_o)$$
$$y-\frac{1}{x_o}=\frac{x_o}{x_o^2}$$
$$y-\frac{1}{x_o}=\frac{1}{x_o}$$
$$y=\frac{2}{x_o}$$

Now use then use the formula $\dfrac12\cdot$base $\cdot$height

$$=\frac12\cdot 2x_o\cdot \frac{2}{x_o}=2$$

So, the area of the triangle enclosed by the axes and the tangent to the parabola $y=\dfrac1x$ at any point on the parabola is $2$ sq.units

Comment: Nice, where did you draw it?

Answer (score 0):

Pick a point on the curve. Once you've found the slope of the tangent at that point, you should be able to calculate the points of intersection with the axes, and thus find the area of the triangle.

If done correctly, the area should be independent of the point chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve this problem:
Assume that the point of tangency is ( k ,1/k), as this point lies on the curve y = 1/x .

1. find the slope
   slope = -1/k^2
2. Then equation of the line.

Equation of the tangent will be : (x/k) + ky = 2.

3. If the equation is ax + by +c =0, then the area will be (1/2)*(c/a)*(c/b), from this you can calculate the area.

Comment: Please consider using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your answer.